# How to deploy telerik reporting REST API(.NET Core 3.1) with docker container+kubernetes on Ubuntu Host OS

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, telerik, telerik-reporting

This is my host os details

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
```

This is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \ 
        libc6-dev \ 
        libgdiplus \ 
        libx11-dev \ 
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
RUN ln -s /shared_storage /app/shared
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80



FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-bionic AS build
WORKDIR /app
#COPY ["MyAPI/MyAPI.csproj", "MyAPI/"]
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore "MyAPI/MyAPI.csproj"
#RUN dotnet build "MyAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
#FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyAPI/MyAPI.csproj" -c Release -o out

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app  
COPY --from=build /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPI.dll"]
```

This docker builds my image without any issue but the problem is, when I am trying to access my telerik report, I am getting

```
Unable to get report parameters.
An error has occurred.
Type: Telerik.Reporting.ReportSerialization.Current.ReportSerializable`1[Telerik.Reporting.Report]
```

NB: I have also tried with mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1.21-bionic

but this image doesn't exist.

NB: On my development environment, I am using windows 10 and from my localhost I am able to generate the reports without any issue.

I am using Telerik Reporting latest Version.
My Nuget.Config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.telerik.com" value="https://nuget.telerik.com/nuget" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <nuget.telerik.com>
      <add key="Username" value="email@mail.com" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="abcdefg" />
    </nuget.telerik.com>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Looks like build statements in dockerfile are commented. Pls uncomment and try again. I believe it won't compile. You'll have to install the 3 linux libraries on build docker image as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error appearing, in the same situation.

Here's what helped me: 
1.Create file: **runtimeconfig.template.json** , inside the main project. 
2.Add this inside:

```
{
  "configProperties": {
    "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
  }
}
```

3.Rebuild.